# How do I draw a circle using JavaScript in R Shiny?

Tags: r, canvas, shiny

I am looking to draw simple shapes in R Shiny. (The goal is to draw a static legend using HTML instead of loading a png.)

I can't get the canvas tag to work. It simply does not draw anything.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$script(HTML(
    "function draw_legend() {",
      "var canvas = document.getElementById('simple_legend');",
      "const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');",
      "const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');",
      "ctx.fillStyle = 'green';",
      "ctx.fillRect(10, 10, 150, 100);",
      "}"
  )),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      tags$body(onload="draw_legend();"),
      tags$canvas(id="simple_legend", height = "30"),
      tags$div("Some text")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Personally, I think it would be far easier to get Shiny to draw your "static legend" for you.  That way you don't have to worry about interfaciong between Javascript and Shiny...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding on my comment, here is an app showing two techniques for drawing a circle in Shiny, one using CSS, the other using a data frame.  You can make obvious adjustments to size, colour, position etc to get the effect you want.

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

ui <-  fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$style("#circleText {color: red; font-size: 20px; }")
  ),
  uiOutput("circleText"),
  plotOutput("circleGraph")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$circleText <- renderUI({
    HTML("&#11044;")
  })
  
  output$circleGraph <- renderPlot({
    tibble(theta=seq(0, 2*pi, 0.025), x=sin(theta), y=cos(theta)) %>% 
      ggplot(aes(x, y)) +
        geom_path() +
        coord_fixed() +
        theme_void()
  },
  height=75,
  width=75)
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Giving

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to

1. remove the line `const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');`
2. set a width to the canvas element, not only a height